# Improper execution in Xcode 7.3.1 and later

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, xcode7

I have an existing application, which uses several static libraries (all of which I am compiling). I am compiling on the command line, with `make` and `clang`, not using the IDE. Previous to Xcode 7.3, all compiled and executed as I expect. With Xcode 7.3, in my release build (which adds `-O2`) I am getting strange behaviour with virtual inline functions - sometimes they return completely garbage values. This seems to happen in classes which have *only* virtual inline methods, eg:

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
       virtual ~MyClass() { }
       virtual int foo()  { return 1; } 
};
```

In my investigation of the issue (trying several related compile flags), it appears adding `-fno-inlines` and/or `-fvisibility-inlines-hidden` works around the issue, and the program executes as expected. However, from my understanding, these are simply hints on how to optimize, and should not affect program execution (specifically, the second should only affect DSOs, which I am not using). This leads me to several questions:

- Searching Apple support forums, I could not find any reference to similar errors. Is this an known issue?
- Is this code somehow malformed? If so, is there some way I can get feedback from the compiler (eg. via a diagnostic) about the problem?
- Why do the compiler flags I mentioned fix the issue? Am I misinterpreting their meaning?

Comment: Which version of `clang` are you using?

Comment: clang --version
`Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin`